# Why was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

I recently submitted a custom flag on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433059/simple-button-widget-size-different-on-different-screen-size) which read

> "Merge into question; These comments seem to be intended as edits to the original question."

However, my flag was declined but then a moderator (who I also assume reviewed the flag) left a comment suggesting the user to do that, with some additional reasoning.

The reason I flagged this, rather than editing the question myself and later raising an flag on the comments was because a) I feel as though the suggested edit queue would have rejected the edit as it significantly modifies the question and b) a flag to delete the comments would have needed to be raised at some point.

Comment: In my experience, those kinds of edits will be approved as long as you mention that you're just adding the OPs comments.

Comment: I'm going to start a new site called whywasmyflagdeclinedoverflow.com

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm the moderator that declined your flag and made the comment.

There was no requirement to bring that to the attention of the moderators - it can be handled by the community.

You could have:

- left a comment for the OP (as I did) suggesting that they should edit into their post and then remove their comments - then the OP/other user may pick that up and act on it
- made a suggested edit specifying clearly you're moving the code from comments into the question

If an edit takes place either way and the comments still hang around then by all means flag them as *obsolete* - removing comments is something only the OP of the comment or a moderator can do.

Comment: That seems to be the consensus here (with myself included) Thanks for coming by and helping to clear that up!

Comment: Every time I read, "I'm the moderator that...", I can't help but think of [Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkUJnmf6po4)

Comment: @codeMagic beats "I'm Spartacus!" hands down :)

Answer (score 11):

Mods tend to decline things that normal users can accomplish by themselves.  Custom flags are more for exceptional circumstances.

In this case, suggest an edit to integrate the comments, and leave a good edit description.  It should be approved assuming that no one else already does it.  After the edit takes place, the comment would likely be "obsolete" and can be flagged as such separately.

Comment: Alternatively, wait for a 2k+ user to come along and do it for you.

Comment: Another alternative: Do as the mod did and leave a comment for the OP to edit the question. This also manages to help teach them to edit their question, potentially better than doing it for them.